# Why does $\int_{-x}^x f^\alpha\leq f(-x)+f(x)$ imply $f=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Let $0\leq f\in C(\mathbb{R})$, and for some $\alpha>1$, we have
> \begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
> \int_{-x}^x f^\alpha\leq f(-x)+f(x), \forall\ x\in [0,+\infty).
> \end{aligned}\end{equation*}
> Prove that $f\equiv 0$.

Let $F(x)=\int_{-x}^x f^\alpha$, then $F'(x)=f^\alpha(x)+f^\alpha(-x)
\leq [f(x)+f(-x)]^\alpha$. How to use the assumption? What to do next? Any ideas?

Comment: Try showing it's sufficient to prove it for even $f$ that are nondecreasing for $x >0$. Then prove that easier statement.

Comment: Can someone told me by the line "For some $\alpha$ " op means $\alpha$ fix or we are allowed to choose $\alpha$ in the proof?

Comment: @Math_Buddy It is for some $\alpha$ not under our control.

Comment: Sir @FShrike Thanks

Comment: @eyeballfrog Would you please give some more hint?  I really do not get it.

Comment: An almost complete solution can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4481288/815585). It remains to show that @eyeballfrog 's hint is valid, specifically, that we really can do the obvious thing and take f nondecreasing w.l.o.g

Comment: @xldd: Any feedback on the answer?

Answer (score 9):

Consider the “even part” $g(x) = \frac 12(f(-x) + f(x))$ for $x \ge 0$. Then
$$
 g(x)^\alpha \le  \max(f(-x), f(x))^\alpha = \max(f(-x)^\alpha, f(x)^\alpha) \le f(-x)^\alpha+ f(x)^\alpha
$$
and therefore
$$
 \int_0^x g(t)^\alpha \, dt \le  \int_{-x}^x f(t)^\alpha \, dt \le f(-x)+f(x) = 2g(x) \, .
$$
The function
$$
 G(x) = \int_0^x g(t)^\alpha \, dt 
$$
is non-negative and differentiable on $[0, \infty)$ with
$$
 G'(x) = g(x)^\alpha  \ge 2^{-\alpha} G(x)^\alpha \, .
$$

Now assume that $G(x_1) > 0$ for some $x_1 > 0$. Then $G$ is positive and increasing on $[x_1, \infty)$, and for all $x_2 > x_1$ is
$$
\frac{1}{\alpha -1} \frac{1}{G(x_1)^{\alpha-1}} \ge
\frac{1}{\alpha -1} \left( \frac{1}{G(x_1)^{\alpha-1}}-\frac{1}{G(x_2)^{\alpha-1}}\right) =
 \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{G'(t)}{G(t)^\alpha} \, dt\\
 \ge \int_{x_1}^{x_2} 2^{-\alpha} \, dt = 2^{-\alpha}(x_2 - x_1) \, .
$$
This is impossible because the right-hand side converges to $(+\infty)$ for $x_2 \to \infty$.

It follows that $G$ is identically zero, and that implies that $g$ is identically zero. Finally,
$$
\int_{-x}^x f(t)^\alpha \, dt \le 2 g(x) = 0
$$
for the non-negative function $f$ implies that $f$ is identically zero.

*Remark:* The proof shows that the assumption $ \int_{-x}^x f(t)^\alpha \, dt \le f(-x)+f(x) $ can be weakened to
$$
 \int_{-x}^x f(t)^\alpha \, dt \le C \bigl(f(-x)+f(x) \bigr)
$$
with an arbitrary constant $C > 0$.

Comment: +1 Nice, very succinct

Comment: @FShrike: There was a sign error in the integration part. I do hope that the new version is correct.

Comment: Looks good to me :)

Comment: I probably need to take more coffee in order to be fully awakened... Why is that $
 \int_0^x g(t)^\alpha \, dt = \int_{-x}^x f(t)^\alpha \, dt$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Not necessarily, what if the last term was positive and negative in different places but always smaller in magnitude than $g$, then $f$ would still be positive

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $\int_{-x}^x f(t)^\alpha dt=\int_0^x(f(t)^\alpha+f(-t)^\alpha)$ by taking $x\mapsto -x$ on $\int_{-x}^0 f(t)^\alpha dt$

Comment: @FShrike basic arithmetic has currently gone beyond me

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I had the same issue when writing my own post!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: Apparently it is me who needs more coffee. There was indeed an error in the argument, which I have fixed now. Thanks for you feedback!