# In proving $\int_{-x}^xf^\alpha\le f(-x)+f(x)$ for nonnegative continuous $f$, $\alpha\gt1$ implies $f\equiv0$, why can we take $f$ nondecreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, solution-verification

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$I have a solution to this problem, but the TlDr is that my solution hinges on the assumption that $f$ is nondecreasing on $[0,\infty)$. It is obvious to me that proving the result for nondecreasing $f$ concludes the result for *all* $f$, but I have struggled to pin down an exact proof - this is what I'd like answered. I know there *is* an answer since another user on this site suggested it as a hint.

Some context: some users may recognise this (deleted) question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4480777/815585). The question received a lot of interest - $7$ upvotes and $5$ favourites at the time of deletion - but the OP (not myself!) deleted it for no clear reason, presumably (from the comments) because they'd figured out the answer or were embarrassed about not having done so. Considering that the post held interest for many other users I feel that the post should *not* be so wantonly deleted, so I am reposting it here with my own (partial) solution.

The question:

> If $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a nonnegative continuous function and $\exists\alpha\gt1$ such that: $$\int_{-x}^x f(t)^\alpha\d t\le f(-x)+f(x),\,\forall x\in\Bbb R$$Prove that $f\equiv0$.

My solution, following a hint from [Eyeballfrog](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/395748/eyeballfrog) left on the original post:

> Let $f(x)=E(x)+O(x)$ be the standard even/odd decomposition. The condition is that, for all $x$: $$\begin{align}2\int_0^x E(t)^\alpha\d t&=\int_{-x}^xE(t)^\alpha\d t\\&=2^{-\alpha}\int_{-x}^x(f(t)^\alpha+f(-t)^\alpha)\d t\\&=2^{1-\alpha}\int_{-x}^xf(t)^\alpha\d t\\&\lt\int_{-x}^xf(t)^\alpha\d t\\&\le f(x)+f(-x)\\&=2E(x)\end{align}$$So if we demonstrate that the above inequality forces $E(x)\equiv0$ we force $f(x)\equiv0$ since $f$ is positive. It suffices to consider $f$ even then.

**It is also sufficient to show the result for $f$ nondecreasing on $[0,\infty)$**. I honestly have struggled to formalise this in a proof - I expect the answer is very simple, though - but it is strongly obvious. A strong proof of why, exactly, we can make this assumption is my question.

With that assumption in mind, we can continue:

> I claim that if $f$ is not identically zero, it must be unbounded. First note that, for an $x\gt0$, $f(x)=0$ forces $f\equiv0$ on $[0,x]$, so for $f$ to not be identically zero there must eventually be an $x_0$ beyond which $f$ is never zero. Suppose $f\le M$ is a bound. For $x_1\gt x_0$ consider $f(x)\ge\int_{x_1}^x f(t)^\alpha\d t$ implies that $M\ge f(x_1)^\alpha(x-x_1)$ with the nondecreasing assumption. However this is obviously false for all $x$ as $f(x_1)\gt0$. Thus, $f$ is unbounded in this case.
>
> Let $\lambda$ be an arbitrary positive real and $x$ such that $f(x)\gt1$ (possible by unboundedness). By the mean value theorem for integrals of continuous functions (and the nondecreasing assertion): $$\lambda f(x)^\alpha\le\lambda f(c)^\alpha=\int_x^{x+\lambda}f(t)^\alpha\d t\le f(x+\lambda)$$So let's integrate: $$\begin{align}f(x+\lambda)&\ge\int_x^{x+\lambda}f(t)^\alpha\d t\\&\ge\int_0^\lambda f(t+x)^\alpha\d t\\&\ge f(x)^{\alpha^2}\int_0^\lambda t^\alpha\d t\\&=\frac{\lambda^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}f(x)^{\alpha^2}\end{align}$$This gives an induction: $$f(x+\lambda)\ge\frac{\lambda^{\alpha^2+\alpha+1}}{(\alpha+1)^\alpha(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)}f(x)^{\alpha^3}\\f(x+\lambda)\ge\frac{\lambda^{\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1}}{(\alpha+1)^{\alpha^2}(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)^{\alpha}(\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1)}f(x)^{\alpha^4}\\f(x+\lambda)\ge\cdots\ge\frac{\lambda^{1+\alpha+\cdots+\alpha^n}}{(\alpha+1)^{\alpha^{n-1}+2\alpha^{n-2}+3\alpha^{n-3}+\cdots+n}}f(x)^{\alpha^n},\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N$$But if $\lambda$ and $f(x)$ are sufficiently large (which can be arranged by unboundedness) then by $f(x)\gt1$, $\alpha\gt1$ we have that the inequality holds for all $n$ only if $f(x+\lambda)=\infty$, which is impossible. Therefore $f\equiv0$ must hold!

So we are done. However, I'd like some feedback on the correctness of the proof and more importantly *I'd like guidance on why we can suppose $f$ is nondecreasing*. It seems so obvious but I can't pin it down...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The link to your referred deleted question is no longer active. So you might as well exclude that from your question. At least from the very first line.

Comment: @sadman-ncc how do you mean "no longer active"? For those who can view deleted posts, it is still viewable. I put it there for context (again, for those who can view it)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. No longer active for those who cannot view deleted posts.

Comment: Put in my vote to undelete the original.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Great! I voted immediately when I saw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since I gave the hint, I suppose I should give my proof. It went like this.

First, we show that
$$
\int_{-x}^xf(t)^\alpha dt = \int_0^x[f(t)^\alpha + f(-t)^\alpha]dt \le \int_0^x[f(t)+ f(-t)]^\alpha dt.
$$
which means that if we can show that if there is an $\alpha$ such that for all $x$,
$$
\int_0^x g(t)^\alpha dt \le g(x)
$$
then $g\equiv 0$, that will be sufficient to prove the original statement. This is where the evenness hint comes in, although I now notice there's actually an irrelevant factor of $2$ between this statement and the original.

Once we have this, we consider the function $h(x) = \inf_{y > x} g(y)$. Clearly, for all $x$, $h(x) \le g(x)$. Secondly, since $\int_0^x g(t)^\alpha dt$ is a nondecreasing function of $x$ and $\int_0^x g(t)^\alpha dt \le g(x)$ for all $x$, we must also have $\int_0^x g(t)^\alpha dt \le h(x)$ for all $x$. Thus we have
$$
\int_0^x h(t)^\alpha dt \le \int_0^x g(t)^\alpha dt \le h(x).
$$
So if we can show that for a nondecreasing function $h$, the existence of some $\alpha$ such that for all $x$,
$$
\int_0^x h(t)^\alpha dt \le h(x)
$$
implies $h\equiv 0$, the above bounds on the integral force $g\equiv 0$.

Comment: Great. Do you agree with my method of conclusion, once a nondecreasing $f$ has been taken?

Comment: @FShrike The idea is similar to what I had in mind. Your first argument that either $f\equiv 0$ or $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$ (note that this is stronger than mere unboundedness) is what I had too. Not quite sure of the rest of it, but the idea that $f$ is now forced to be larger than $1$ somewhere and thus can be made to blow up too fast is the route I started down.

Comment: This question interested me greatly, as a student. I’m interested to see how else you can force a blow-up. I thought long and hard yesterday and the only blow-up approach I could see was the one I took, with arbitrary iterated integration of increasing powers. Would you mind giving a brief description of your approach? I toyed with doing Riemann partitions on the integrals but unfortunately couldn’t make it work. P.S. you might be interested in Martin Rs answer to the original post